# Properties are pasted as plain text in fckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using fckeditor for my application. Problem is when I make a template and define properties in it in a window and then If I paste this template to another fckeditor window, properties become plain text. Is there any way they are pasted as properties??
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these properties, we are using a separate plugin which I was not aware of at the time of asking this question.
Did a little tweaking with this plugin and achieved the motive.